# Warning when using subfiles

Tags: warnings, subfiles

So I'm getting this warning whenever I typeset a document which is using the `subfiles` package for modular documents. The warning occurs both when running the master file as well as the individual parts.

```
/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/auxhook.sty: Package auxhook Warning: Cannot patch \document,(auxhook)                using \AtBeginDocument instead.
```

It's *just* a warning, and it doesn't seem to change anything at all. Everything looks good. It's just that I prefer *not* to have warnings...

Any ideas?

Comment: it means `\document` didn't have the expected definition, presumably something else has already patched it, impossible to say what as you provided no example.

Comment: @Argo Have you found the problem?